# Bash searching for pairs

Tags: bash

I have two files which I want to pair up and save the index of the first file with the corresponding index on the second file if they match.

For example:

**Textfile1**

```
a
b
c
d
e
d
e
c
```

**Textfile2**

```
c
e
e
d
b
a
```

**Output**

```
(1,6) (2,5) (3,1) (4,4) (5,3) (5,2) (6,4) (7,3) (7,2) (8,1)
```

I tried using nl for numbering the rows, join for joining to pairs and sorting to sort the pairs but I don't get it.

Comment: Add to your question what you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Could you please check solutions and let us know if those helped you?

Answer (score 1):

With awk, read second file into an array and loop through it for printing matches while reading first file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0,++n[$0]]=NR; next } ($0 in n) { for (i=1;i<=n[$0];i++) printf "(%d, %d)\n",FNR,a[$0,i] }' file2 file1
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do it somehow with join, nl and sort?

Comment: @bktllr I don't know. Give it a couple of hours and someone will come up with that if  possible

Answer (score 0):

could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0,++b[$0]]=FNR
  next
}
{
  if(b[$0]>=++c[$0]){
    if(b[$0]==1){
      print "("FNR","a[$0,++d[$0]]")"
    }
    else{
      for(i=1;i<=b[$0];i++){
        print "("FNR","a[$0,i]")"
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    c[$0]--
    print "("FNR","a[$0,d[$0]]?a[$0,d[$0]]:0")"
  }
}
'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
(1,6)
(2,5)
(3,1)
(4,4)
(5,2)
(5,3)
(6,4)
(7,2)
(7,3)
(8,1)
```

Comment: Weird, what do all those ifs do? What makes this different than mine?

Comment: @oguzismail, very honestly I your solution after posting mine(though it was showing 1 answer loaded  etc I  haven't clicked on it :) ), asap you mentioned that it is not working I started working on it. Then I compared and found a  minor difference that I am checking length and if any character comes only 1 time it will NOT run for loop is what I could find  the difference. If it doesn't look ok, lemme know I have no hesitation to delete after your advice :) buddy

Comment: Nah it's not a problem for me, I just wondered if I missed something important

Comment: @oguzismail, ok after going to bed, I just remember one thing(good in case you have already taken care of it) in case any element is not present in another file it will print 0 on its place value cheers and have a great day ahead, gn buddy.

Comment: Nope I didn't realize that b4 but fixed now. Thanks